# Entity Framework not showing some entities

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4

I am using MVC 3 with EF. I have created a entitymodel from SQL Server db and some of the tables are not showing in diagram and in code in intellisence. I have created the model again but same problem. Those tables having many to many relationship not appearing in diagram or entity list, shown in table store. At the same time few other tables with many to many relationships are visible. What is missing here? I have check PK and FK all seems correct. SQL Server also shows them in diagram but not in Visual Studio Entity model diagram.

It is something like

### Department

DeptID
(other fields)

### Phones

PhoneID
Phone

### Has_Phone (this is many to many) and not showing up in entity model

PhoneID
DeptID

How can I get all the phones using LINQ for a departmentID?

Please help Thanks  QF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

If the table has only two fields, the primary keys from two other tables then EF behaves like that. The solution is to create just one more column in MNM table and update the model from database. And finally the solution will be resolved itself.

If someone knows any other better solution then please share with us.